# Can I make my Gnosis Safe owner of my NFT platform smart contracts?

Tags: smart-contract-wallets, gnosis-safe

I need a multi-sig setup for my NFT platform smart contracts (minting and marketplace smart contracts). Can I use my Gnosis Safe for this?

In particular, if I transfer ownership of the smart contracts to my Gnosis Safe, will I be able to then use my Gnosis Safe to transfer ownership to another address later? And, while the Gnosis Safe is owner, can I use it to sign transactions such as assigning the minter role, upgrading the smart contract, etc?

I've asked around about this, and I've heard answers that range from 'Gnosis Safe can interact with any smart contract' to 'the smart contract has to support the EIP-1271 Standard for this to work, and this is often not the case', so I'm a bit confused :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can.

Look under the apps, there is a transaction builder that will let you call anything. Just verify the contract or pass it the ABI.